# How to resolve PoolableConnectionFactory exception in JMeter when trying to connect AWS postgres db in JMeter?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, jdbc, jmeter

Here is how Database url is given : jdbc:postgresql://Hostname:portnumber/dbname

Kept the following jar file in C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-jmeter-5.0\lib
postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar

I am getting the below error in JMeter when trying to connect AWS postgres db in JMeter.

Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx", user "xxuser", database "xxname", SSL off).

Comment: That means you failed to authenticate. Did you mean to set a username and password?

Answer (score 0):

Can it be the case you have SSL enabled in your PostgreSQL cluster? Looking at [**Requiring an SSL/TLS connection to an Aurora PostgreSQL DB cluster** chapter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Security.html)

> If you enable set rds.force_ssl and restart your DB cluster, non-SSL connections are refused with the following message:
>
> ```
> psql: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "host.ip", user "someuser", database "postgres", SSL off
> ```

So it might be the case you just need to enable SSL in your JDBC URL like:

```
jdbc:postgresql://Hostname:portnumber/dbname?ssl=true
```

Otherwise just add the following entry to your pg_hba.conf file:

```
hostnossl    all          all            0.0.0.0/0  trust
```

and upon Postgres restart you will be able to connect from anywhere by anyone without SSL

Also according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) and [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to JMeter 5.4.1 (or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T. I got it resolved by adding 
?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory     to the url.

JDBC URL like:
jdbc:postgresql://Hostname:portnumber/dbname?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory

Answer (score 0):

If the server does not support ssl connection, then add this as Database URL:

```
jdbc:postgresql://hostname:portnumber/dbname
```

Otherwise add this as Databse URL:

```
jdbc:postgresql://hostname:portnumber/dbname?ssl=true
```